# Function to return beta coefficients B0 and B1

Tags: python, function, statistics

Here is what I am trying to do. Create a function that takes two series (x,y) then calculates and returns the intercept and slope coefficients that minimize SSE.

I have written a function below that takes two series and returns the intercept (B0) and the slope (B1) for a linear regression equation. Problem? The values look wrong to me. I know this is a rough way to write this function. Tips on how to improve?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def coeff(Series_y,Series_x):
    beta_0 = 0
    beta_1 = 0
    y_list = Series_y.tolist()
    x_list = Series_x.tolist()
    y_list_array = np.array(y_list)
    x_list_array = np.array(x_list)
    y_list_mean = np.mean(y_list_array)
    x_list_mean = np.mean(x_list_array)
    y_list_stdev = np.std(y_list_array)
    x_list_stdev = np.std(x_list_array)
    r_x_y = np.corrcoef(x_list_array,y_list_array)
    beta_1 = r_x_y * (y_list_stdev/x_list_stdev)
    beta_0 = y_list_mean - (beta_1 * x_list_mean)
    return beta_0
    return beta_1
    print(beta_0, beta_1)
```

I rewrote this function. It is still very clunky.

```
# create the needed variables
beta_0 = 0
beta_1 = 0
r_x_y = 0
y_list = 0
x_list = 0
y_list_array = 0
x_list_array = 0
y_list_mean = 0
x_list_mean = 0
y_list_stdev = 0
x_list_stdev = 0 
def coeff(Series_y,Series_x):
    # create the two needed beta variables
    # calculate needed stats
    y_list = Series_y.tolist()
    x_list = Series_x.tolist()
    y_list_array = np.array(y_list)
    x_list_array = np.array(x_list)
    y_list_mean = np.mean(y_list_array)
    x_list_mean = np.mean(x_list_array)
    y_list_stdev = np.std(y_list_array)
    x_list_stdev = np.std(x_list_array)    
    r_x_y = np.corrcoef(x_list_array,y_list_array)
    return x_list_mean, y_list_mean, x_list_stdev, y_list_stdev, r_x_y
    # calculate the beta coefficients
    beta_1 = r_x_y * (y_list_stdev/x_list_stdev)
    beta_0 = y_list_mean - (beta_1 * x_list_mean)
    return beta_0, beta_1
    # Return line of best fit.
    return beta_0 + beta_1 * x
    print(beta_0 + beta_1 * x)
```

I rewrote it using Bill's suggestion. Much easier!

```
def coeff(Series1, Series2):
    return print(scipy.stats.linregress(Series1, Series2))
```

Comment: Since you're using an existing library, namely `np`, to do some of the calculations for you, I assume that you might not be averse to having one that does it all. Then you could use https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html.

Comment: Thanks, Bill! So much to learn in this area.